# Can I weight a weighing machine by putting it upside down?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

For the sake of this question let us assume a flatbed scale where I can put the mass on top in order to measure on a flat surface which forms the top of the scale:

Will it give correct reading if I turn it upside down? My thought is that the floor will see a normal force equal to the weight of the machine and thus the scale will give the weight of machine. Am i thinking right?

Comment: Good thought, but not quite. A bathroom scale has a bottom part that sits on the floor. This contains the mechanism and most of the mass. The top plate you stand on also has some mass. When you stand on the scale, you squeeze it between you and the floor. If you don't stand on it, the weight of the top presses down on the scale. The scale is adjusted so this amount of weight shows as $0$. If you turn it upside down, you replace this with the weight of the mechanism. If all the mass was in the bottom and none in the top, your idea would work.

Comment: I'd like to see this question re-opened

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the design of your weighting machine, if you use a beam balance that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a bathroom scales type machine as being in three parts.
A base, a top pan and a device connecting the two which produces a reading in kilogrammes/pounds.
When the right way up the scale reading is zero so the weight of the top pan is compensated for and the base has no effect on the reading.

Inverting the scales will produce a reading which is the difference between the weight of the base and the weight of the top pan and that reading will be positive as I would expect the weight of the base to be greater than that of the top pan.

You can then take that difference reading away from the scale reading when an object is placed on the base and that will give you a reading for the weight of the object.